# How to integrate Dialogflow with Chatbase for easier bot analytics?

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, chatbase

I have created a Conversational Interface for Android With Dialogflow to conduct an intelligent conversation between customer and bot. Now to make it more proficient, I have to integrate Chatbase.

As per https://chatbase.com/documentation/dialogflow-integration, Chatbase is currently available only via a server-to-server integration and therefore is incompatible with Dialogflow hosted bots.

Is there a way to use the Chatbase with android?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a look at [Webhooks](https://dialogflow.com/docs/tutorial-build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook) provided by DialogFlow. They allow you to write custom code in response to each user request. It would be surprising if there isn't a canned one for Chatbase integration.